# Select rows that match values in multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I select rows that match values in multiple columns?

For example, we have the following df

```
k1 | k2 | v1 | v2
1  | 2  | 3  | 4
1  | 5  | 5  | 6
1  | 8  | 8  | 9
```

I am trying to select the middle row:

```
key_names = ["k1", "k2"]
keys = [1, 5]
selected_rows = df.loc[df[key_names].isin(keys)]
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

The expected output is :

```
1  | 5  | 5  | 6
```

Thanks

Comment: `df[(df[key_names] == keys).all(1)]`.  If you don't want exact ordering: `df[df[key_names].isin(keys).all(1)]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***TLDR***

Use one of the following, based on your requirements:

```
df[(df[key_names] == keys).all(1)]

df[df[key_names].isin(keys).all(1)]
```

---

You're quite close, you have successfully created your mask, you just need to reduce it to a single dimension for indexing.

```
>>> df[key_names].isin(keys)
     k1     k2
0  True  False
1  True   True
2  True  False
```

You are only interested in rows where *all* values, are `True`, and so you can reduce the dimension using `all` across the first axis.

```
>>> df[key_names].isin(keys).all(1)
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

The one caveat here is that `isin` is not order dependent, so you would get the same results using another ordering of your values.

```
>>> df[key_names].isin([5, 1]).all(1)
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

If you only want an exact ordering match, use `==` for broadcasted comparison, instead of `isin`

```
>>> (df[key_names] == keys).all(1)
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

>>> (df[key_names] == [5, 1]).all(1)
0    False
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

---

The last step here is using the `1D` mask you've created to index the original DataFrame:

```
>>> df[(df[key_names] == keys).all(1)]
   k1  k2  v1  v2
1   1   5   5   6
```

Comment: thank you for so detailed answer, it definitely seems like a correct way of doing it - e.g ordering and all. But I still have a problem of the same error "ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key" ... do you know why it may happen?

Comment: so I guess the error is caused by what is passed to loc, in particular the output of (df[key_names] == keys).all(1) has shape (3,) so maybe this is a problem coz it is treated as 2d..

Comment: yeah, I needed to first convert it to a list

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *df.query('k1 == 1 and k2 == 5')* will be enough?

Or `df[df.apply(lambda row: {1,5} == set((row.k1, row.k2)), axis=1)]`

The second solution will work at any keys order.